# Javascript uncaught syntaxerror unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

Basically, the method prints a list with values and when I click on a value, I get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on line 6.

As a result,I am unable to pass the value that I click on,onto the liveSearch method. I have tried searching the net in hopes of solving the error but to no avail,I couldn't find a solution. Please advise.

```
function printSuggestResult(arrOfSuggestText,getRows){
    var htmlStr  = "<button id='dropdownB' href='#' class='dropdown-toggle btn btn-default'data-toggle='dropdown'>Found  <span id='resultCount' class='badge'></span> &nbsp</b></button><ul class='list-group  scrollable-menu'>";

    for(var i=0; i<arrOfSuggestText.length; i++){
        htmlStr += "<li class='list-group-item '>";

        if(arrOfSuggestText[i] != "null"){
            htmlStr +=  '<a id="searchResult'+i+'" href="javascript:liveSearch('+arrOfSuggestText[i]+')" > '+arrOfSuggestText[i]+'</a>';
        }
        htmlStr += "</li>";
    }

    htmlStr += "</ul>";

    document.getElementById('searchResultList').innerHTML = htmlStr;
        $('#resultCount').text(getRows);
    }

function liveSearch(getText){
    var arrOfText = new Array();
    var arrOfLat = new Array();
    var arrOfLon = new Array();

    getText = getText.replace(" ","+");
    var testy = encodeURIComponent(getText);
}
```

Comment: *"I get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier."* ***On what line?***

Comment: htmlStr +=  '<a id="searchResult'+i+'" href="javascript:liveSearch('+arrOfSuggestText[i]+')" > '+arrOfSuggestText[i]+'</a>';

Comment: `htmlStr +=  '<a id="searchResult'+i+'" href="javascript:liveSearch('+arrOfSuggestText[i]+')" > '+arrOfSuggestText[i]+'</a>';` There are tons of " ' mistakes in this line.

Comment: Can you please assist me to the correct syntax.

Comment: @user1354678 Where? I can only think that `liveSearch` needs some `"` around the value. Otherwise, the concatenation is fine.

Comment: It may also be worth pointing out that you should use [DOM manipulation](http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation) to save yourself the headache of concatenating strings for `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
htmlStr +=  '<a id="searchResult'+i+'" href="javascript:liveSearch('+arrOfSuggestText[i]+')" > '+arrOfSuggestText[i]+'</a>';
```

and concrete here `'" href="javascript:liveSearch('+arrOfSuggestText[i]+')" > '` you try create calling function, but if you see value of this string, for `arrOfSuggestText[i] == 'qwe'`  you can see something like

```
href="javascript:liveSearch(qwe)"
```

and browser raise error what you get on `qwe`.

So you need just add quotes around like

```
'" href="javascript:liveSearch(\''+arrOfSuggestText[i]+'\')" > '
```

Comment: It works! I have learnt something valuable thanks to you! Thank you very much!