# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, single quote error

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

The `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error occurs at line number 5` whenever I try to put in a single quote in the array.

I am unable to use any escape characters in my search. I need to able to type St George's Station and the liveSearch method should be invoked to conduct the search.

I know for a fact that the single quote is a special character in the javascript. Is there any way to get around the error?

P.S I'm still a newbie in javascript so please go easy on me :).

```
var htmlStr  = "<ul class='list-group  scrollable-menu'>";
  for(var i=0; i<arrOfSuggestText.length; i++){
    htmlStr += "<li class='list-group-item '>";
     if(arrOfSuggestText[i] != "null"){
        htmlStr +=  '<a id="searchResult'+i
                     +'" href="javascript:liveSearch(\''+arrOfSuggestText[i]+'\')" > '+
                     arrOfSuggestText[i]+'</a>';
     }
     htmlStr += "</li>";
  }
  htmlStr += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById('searchResultList').innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```

Comment: I [remember this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555599/javascript-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-error) :) You should use DOM manipulation instead of innerHTML and inline event handlers, then you won't have any issues with apostrophes, quotes or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `'` with a `\`: that's it: `St George\'s Station`, or, if it doesn't fit you (because there are other quotes), you can convert it to the escaping character `\x27`.

In this case: `St George\x27s Station`